# Python function running differently on a separate file vs on a larger file

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

So I developed a function outside my main python code file (so that I stop the login hassle each time I test). But the function does not run properly within the main code, although it runs perfectly as a separate file.
Here are important parts of the function:

```
def display_transaction_master():
    def add_transaction():
        product = product_var.get()
        transaction_type = transaction_type_var.get()
        qty = qty_entry.get()
        rate = rate_var.get()
        amount = str(float(qty) * float(rate))
        date = f"{day_var.get()} {month_var.get()} {year_var.get()}"
        
        # Format rate and amount to two significant figures
        rate = "{:.2f}".format(float(rate))
        amount = "{:.2f}".format(float(amount))

        # Add the transaction to the table
        transaction_tree.insert("", "end", values=(product, transaction_type, qty, rate, amount, date))
        
        # Optionally, clear the input fields
        product_var.set("")
        transaction_type_var.set("")
        qty_entry.delete(0, "end")
        rate_var.set("")
        global unsaved_changes
        unsaved_changes = True

    def update_transaction():
        global unsaved_changes
        unsaved_changes = True  # Set the flag to True when changes are made
        selected_item = transaction_tree.selection()[0]
        product_name = product_var.get()
        qty = qty_entry.get()
        date = f"{day_var.get()} {month_var.get()} {year_var.get()}"
        transaction_type = transaction_type_var.get()

        # Fetch rate from products.csv based on the selected product and transaction type
        rate = rate_entry.get()

        # Calculate amount
        amount = f'{float(qty) * float(rate):.2f}'

        transaction_tree.item(selected_item, values=(product_name, transaction_type, qty, rate, amount, date))
        clear_entries()

    def on_double_click(event):
        item = transaction_tree.selection()[0]
        print(item)
        values = transaction_tree.item(item, "values")
        print(values)
        if values:
            product_name, transaction_type, qty, rate, amount, date = values
            product,type,qty,rate,amn,dat = product_name, transaction_type, qty, rate, amount, date
            product_var.set(product)
            qty_entry.delete(0, "end")
            qty_entry.insert(0, qty)
            day, month, year = dat.split()
            day_var.set(day)
            month_var.set(month)
            year_var.set(year)
            transaction_type_var.set(type)
            rate_var.set(rate)

    def fetch_rate(selected_product, selected_transaction_type):
        # Read the CSV file and find the rate based on the product and transaction type
        with open('products.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
            csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in csvreader:
                product_name = row[0]
                purchase_rate = float(row[1])
                sale_rate = float(row[2])

                if product_name == selected_product:
                    if selected_transaction_type == "Purchase":
                        return f'{purchase_rate:.2f}'
                    elif selected_transaction_type == "Sale":
                        return f'{sale_rate:.2f}'
        return ""  # Return an empty string if the rate is not found

    # Function to update the rate based on selected product and transaction type
    def update_rate(event):
        selected_product = product_var.get()
        selected_transaction_type = transaction_type_var.get()

        # Fetch the rate from the products CSV based on the selected product and transaction type
        rate = fetch_rate(selected_product, selected_transaction_type)
        
        # Update the rate in the rate textbox
        rate_var.set(rate)

        
    def set_rate():
        selected_product = product_var.get()
        selected_transaction_type = transaction_type_var.get()

        # Fetch the rate from the products CSV based on the selected product and transaction type
        rate = fetch_rate(selected_product, selected_transaction_type)
        
        # Update the rate in the rate textbox
        rate_var.set(rate)

    def save_transactions():
        with open('transactions.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
            for row_id in transaction_tree.get_children():
                values = transaction_tree.item(row_id)['values']
                csvwriter.writerow(values)
        messagebox.showinfo("Saved", "Transactions have been saved.")
        global unsaved_changes
        unsaved_changes = False

    def on_closing():
        global unsaved_changes
        if unsaved_changes:
            response = messagebox.askyesnocancel("Save Changes", "Do you want to save changes before closing?")
            if response is None:
                return  # User clicked "Cancel", do not close the window
            if response:
                save_transactions()  # Save changes if the user clicked "Yes"
        transaction_master_window.destroy()

    def clear_entries():
        product_var.set("")  # Reset the product dropdown
        qty_entry.delete(0, "end")
        rate_var.set("")
        day_var.set(current_date.day)
        month_var.set(current_date.strftime("%b"))
        year_var.set(current_date.year)
        transaction_type_var.set("")  # Reset transaction type dropdown

    # Function to load transactions from a CSV file and populate the table
    def load_transactions():
        # Clear the existing rows in the table
        for row in transaction_tree.get_children():
            transaction_tree.delete(row)
        
        # Read data from the "transactions.csv" file and populate the table
        with open('transactions.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
            csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in csvreader:
                product, transaction_type, qty, rate, amount, date = row
                transaction_tree.insert("", "end", values=(product, transaction_type, qty, rate, amount, date))

    # Flag to track changes
    unsaved_changes = False

    transaction_master_window = tk.Tk()
    transaction_master_window.title("Transaction Master")

    transaction_frame = tk.Frame(transaction_master_window)
    transaction_frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

    # Fetch product names from the CSV file
    products = []
    with open('products.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in csvreader:
            product_name = row[0]
            products.append(product_name)
```

So as a standalone file this function works perfectly, however when added to the main project file it breaks down. I have debugged it and the variables are fetched correctly its just the `.set` command doesn't work. The funny thing is that if I call the function from the IDLE shell it runs perfectly too (the main file). It just doesn't work when called by the main code. I have no idea what the issue could be, can it just be an interpreter issue?
This is the continuation of the function:

```
product_var = tk.StringVar()
product_dropdown = create_dropdown(transaction_frame, "Product:", products, 0, 0, product_var, width=12)

qty_entry = create_entry(transaction_frame, "Qty:", 0, 2, tk.StringVar())

day_var = tk.StringVar()
month_var = tk.StringVar()
year_var = tk.StringVar()
days = [str(day) for day in range(1, 32)]
months = list(calendar.month_abbr)[1:]
years = [str(year) for year in range(date.today().year, date.today().year + 11)]
day_dropdown = create_dropdown(transaction_frame, "Day:", days, 0, 4, day_var, width=3)
month_dropdown = create_dropdown(transaction_frame, "Month:", months, 0, 6, month_var, width=5)
year_dropdown = create_dropdown(transaction_frame, "Year:", years, 0, 8, year_var, width=4)

current_date = datetime.now().date()
day_var.set(current_date.day)
month_var.set(current_date.strftime("%b"))
year_var.set(current_date.year)

transaction_type_options = ["Purchase", "Sale"]
transaction_type_var = tk.StringVar()
transaction_type_dropdown = create_dropdown(transaction_frame, "Transaction Type:", transaction_type_options, 1, 0, transaction_type_var, width=12)

rate_var = tk.StringVar()
rate_entry = create_entry(transaction_frame, "Rate:", 1, 2, rate_var, state="readonly")

product_dropdown.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", update_rate)
transaction_type_dropdown.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", update_rate)

add_button = tk.Button(transaction_frame, text="Add", font=("Helvetica", 16), command=add_transaction)
add_button.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

update_button = tk.Button(transaction_frame, text="Update", font=("Helvetica", 16), command=update_transaction)
update_button.grid(row=1, column=6, padx=10, pady=10)

save_button = tk.Button(transaction_frame, text="Save", font=("Helvetica", 16), command=save_transactions)
save_button.grid(row=1, column=8, padx=10, pady=10)

transaction_tree = ttk.Treeview(transaction_frame, columns=("Product", "Transaction Type", "Qty", "Rate", "Amount", "Date"), show="headings")
transaction_tree.heading("Product", text="Name")
transaction_tree.heading("Transaction Type", text="Transaction Type")
transaction_tree.heading("Qty", text="Qty")
transaction_tree.heading("Rate", text="Rate")
transaction_tree.heading("Amount", text="Amount")
transaction_tree.heading("Date", text="Date")

transaction_tree.column("Product", width=250)
transaction_tree.column("Transaction Type", width=175)
transaction_tree.column("Qty", width=175)
transaction_tree.column("Rate", width=175)
transaction_tree.column("Amount", width=175)
transaction_tree.column("Date", width=175)

transaction_tree.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=9, padx=10, pady=10)

load_transactions()

transaction_tree.bind("<Double-1>", on_double_click)
transaction_master_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

transaction_master_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Where do you define `product_var` and all the other variables you use with `.set()`?

Comment: Please show how you're embedding this in the script that doesn't work.

Comment: It may be due to multiple instances of `Tk()` if there is another instance created in your main application.

Comment: @Barmar I have edited in the rest of the function in.

Comment: @acw1668 I'm sorry, what do you mean multiple instances of `Tk()`, I have 3 instances of it, but the other 2 work fine and have similar functions.
`  root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Login Page")
`
`   transaction_master_window = tk.Tk()
    transaction_master_window.title("Transaction Master")
`
`    product_master_window = tk.Tk()
    product_master_window.title("Product Master")
`

Comment: If you change `tk.Tk()` to `tk.Toplevel()`, does it work when calling from your main application?

Comment: @acw1668 Oh yes it did, Thank you! Is there any specific reason `Tk()` doesn't work in this instance?

Comment: Note that tkinter variable (`StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc) created without specifying the `master` will be created inside the first instance of `Tk()`.  If it is used with widget of another instance of `Tk()`, it will not work properly.